# Generic Type Linked List in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm making a linked list in TypeScript and want to type guard the value type of the link node to be the same as all link nodes in the list. Is this behavior possible?

- Generic Single Link Node

```
class SingleLink<T> {
  next: SingleLink<T> | null;

  constructor(public value: T) {
    this.next = null;
  }
}
```

- Linked List

```
class LinkedList<T> {
  private len: number;
  private hd: SingleLink<T> | null;
  private tl: SingleLink<T> | null;

  constructor() {
    this.len = 0;
    this.hd = null;
    this.tl = null;
  }

  // properties getters
  // ...
  // ...

  push(input: T) {
    const link = new SingleLink(input);

    if(this.tl) {
      this.tl.next = link;
      this.tl = link;
    } else {
      this.hd = link;
      this.hd.next = link;
      this.tl = link;
    }

    return ++this.len;
  }


  // methods ...
  // ...
}
```

- Desired Behavior

```
const li1 = new LinkedList();

li1.push(10) // li1 should only accept number

li1.push("a") // type error

const li2 = new LinkedList();

li2.push("A") // li2 should only accept string
li2.push(15) // type error
```

- Current Behavior

currently the Linked List accepts any type

```
const li = new LinkedList();

li.push(15);
li.push("a"); // No type error occur
```

Comment: `const li1 = new LinkedList<number>();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const li1 = new LinkedList<number>();

li1.push(10)

li1.push("a") // Errors out
```

If you don't mention the type to LinkedList, by default it assumes it to be `unknown` and hence it accepts values of all types